# How Can I Get the First Character of Standard Input and Throw Out the Rest?

Tags: c

I know I can get the first character of a line of standard input by using getchar(), but I *only* want the first character of each line. Is there a function I can use to get rid of the rest of the string entered into standard input (if it is more than one character)? if not, what methodology should I consider using to get rid of the rest of the standard input line?

Comment: So read in the line and just use the first element of your buffer.

Comment: Another way:`int char=getchar(),c;if(char!='\n'&&char!=EOF)while((c=getchar())!='\n'&&c!=EOF);`

Answer (score 5):

```
char buf[100];
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) != NULL)
{
   if(strlen(buf)>0)
      buf[1] = '\0';
   printf("%s",buf);
}
```

Read the whole line using `fgets()` and just nul terminate it after the first character.

Comment: This will go wrong if the file happens to contain lines longer than 98 characters.

Comment: @joop `fgets()` expects a buffer, to hold the line and it has to be large enough to accomodate the whole line.. That care needs to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch;
size_t len;

for (len = 0;   1;      ) {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if (!len++) putc(ch, stdout); /* the first character on a line */
        if (ch == '\n') len = 0;        /* the line has ended */
        }
return 0;
}
```

Please note that the first character on a line can actually be a `'\n'` !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the character you need
char c = getchar();

// Skip the rest
int a;
while((a = getchar()) != '\n' && a != EOF);
```

If you know how many lines you'll have, you can put it in a loop.